# onMouseEntered doesn't work properly JavaFX

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

I am drawing a Circle and a Text on a Pane and what I want is to have a text appear next to the cursor that says "Mouse is over the circle" when it is over the circle and "Mouse is outside the circle" when its outside. What happens instead is the text always says "Mouse is outside the circle" except in some locations over the circle (and even then it tends to flash back to the wrong one). I also tried setting the text directly from the mouseEntered and mouseExited events and its even worse. What am I doing wrong? Better yet, is there another way of determining whether the cursor is over a certain node? Also if you could explain to me why I get a "variable used in lambda expression should be effectively final" when I move the definition of s inside the start method, it would be great :)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Ex1512 extends Application {
    String s="";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Text text = new Text();
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 50);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setOnMouseEntered(e -> s = "Mouse is over the circle");
        circle.setOnMouseExited(e -> s = "Mouse is outside the circle");
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            text.setText(s);
            text.setX(e.getX());
            text.setY(e.getY());
        });
        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle,text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,300,300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the text over the circle. So the text receives the event, then the circle again. Just relocate the text away from the mouse cursor.

This solves your problem:

```
text.setX(e.getX()+20);
```

Or you could use [setMouseTransparent](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent%28boolean%29) on the text.

Comment: Wow thanks. I am a noob you see, i would have never thought of that. I assumed that the circle event triggers all the time regardless of whats on top of it and since the text doesnt handle any events it doesnt make any difference where it is. Any thoughts on the part where i ask how to determine whether the mouse is over a node (e.g from a separate key event)?

Comment: I updated the answer. You could as well use setMouseTransparent on the Text, so that it doesn't receive events. Regarding the determination I'd prefer to use circle.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, ...);